# How to generate Gray codes of n bits that have at max k ones?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I understand Gray codes have one bit change between them and how to convert between binary and gray. But given a bit length of **n**, I want to generate a series of Gray codes (all possible) that have one bit change and have maximum **k** ones.
Example: Given `n = 3`  and `k = 2` 
`001 011 010 110 100 101`

Comment: I found a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085584/gray-code-for-all-k-element-subset-of-1-n) but I don't fully understand the answer given by @sh1 and it is not exactly what I need so I opened a new question

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The example you gave fails the cyclic property of Gray codes because two bits have to change when rolling around from `101` back to `000`. For other other combinations like n=5 and k=2, it would only be possible to include a small subset of all numbers with no more than k bits set.

Comment: Ahh yes sorry ... What if I were to exclude that combination? I'll edit the question thanks @squeamishossifrage

Comment: Both `000` and `111` are allowed if starting from `001`. What is the rule to exclude them? Isn't it contradicting `all possible` rule? I understand `k` as maximum allowed differences between initial element and any element in the sequence.

Comment: @MirMasej `k` is the maximum number of one in the bitstring. `111` has `3` ones and if we include `000` cyclic gray codes may not be possible as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I can think of which is quite different from Gray code generation would be in general:

- generate all numbers within `k` (Hamming distance)
- generate all possible valid combinations of above and pick the longest one(s).

But I don't like it because, you need to store all the numbers in a Set and use try and error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it is possible to devise such a code.  Here's an informal outline of a proof for the case `n=4, k=2`.  There will be 4 codes with 1 bit set and 6 with 2 bits set.

Start with `0000` (though I don't think it matters where the coding actually starts since a Gray code wraps round).  Then the next code will have 1 bit set.  The next in sequence must have 2 bits set, the one after that 1 bit, then 2, then 1, then 2, then 1, then 2, and you still have 2 codes with 2 bits set left ...

Comment: Ahh I see.... but it is definitely interesting to look at what we could do to have least possible changed bits between consecutive codes. It is no longer gray then though Thanks